# Selecting rows based on a SQL Server "bit" column

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

In a SQL Server table, I have a `BIT` column and based its value, I need to update that table's other columns with some values. I tried this

```sql
UPDATE tablename SET Completed = GETDATE() WHERE CheckTaskAvailable = TRUE
```

but I get the error

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server SQLDEV01, Line 1
Invalid column name 'TRUE'.
```

How to do this in a T-SQL query?

Comment: with what value you want to update it ?

Comment: Update TableName set ColumnName = 1/*0*/

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande In that table I have columns like Task Name, Completed, TaskAdded Date, CheckTaskAvailable.  'CheckTaskAvailable' is have bit as data type, based on this I need update 'Completed' column as 0 or 1.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to set as `true` try

```
Update table set columnName = 1 where ...
```

if you want to set as `false` try

```
Update table set columnName = 0 where ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using the values 0 and 1, the [T-SQL documentation for bit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms177603.aspx) says that

> The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.

so these work, too:

```sql
UPDATE tablename SET bitcolumn = 'TRUE' WHERE ...

UPDATE tablename SET othercolumn = 'something' WHERE bitcolumn = 'TRUE'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a need to do something similar where I was looking to update a field based on whether a record existed or not existed in another table so I used above code (thank you RezaRahmati) and added:

`Update table set columnName = 1 where ID IN (SELECT ID FROM other table)`

or for false

`Update table set columnName = 0 where ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM other table)`

I really enjoy Stack Overflow it has really helped me learn.